# Run http.server and do stuff at once, python

Tags: python, http.server

is there any way to figure this out? I want to run a command invisibly and do stuff at once

```
import os

def run():
    os.system("python -m http.server C:/Showtape/payload/payload.exe 80")
    print("Server running...")
    print("Serving payload..")
```

What i wanted is, I want the command running invisibly and print the "Server running...",
how im gonna do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `http.server` module directly in your code instead of shelling out to start a new Python process. You could start the server in a thread, for instance.

[This source code in `http/server.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e6d1aa1ac65b6908fdea2c70ec3aa8c4f1dffcb5/Lib/http/server.py#L1257-L1294) is exactly what happens when you run `python -m http.server`